# How to enable downloading from amazon ec2 iis

Tags: iis, amazon-web-services

I am new to amazon aws platform. I deployed a static theme in my ec2 iis.

```
http://54.172.56.171/index.html
```

but the other pages are not able to access.

actually i want to download a zip file and mp4 video file from here but those url says me 500 error.

```
http://54.172.56.171/SC122_PressKit.zip
```

Could anyone tell me what mistake I made.

Comment: The PressKit URL works fine for me. It's probably working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you need to install the static file module in IIS. This is unrelated to AWS, but will be required by IIS no matter where your server was.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2196177

Answer (score 0):

Thanks E. J. Brennan.

From your comment I got the initial clue. but in my server that static file module was installed and was running but I got that asp_state service was stopped. I just started all services listed there then its start working.

Please see the following image

```
http://54.172.56.171/serverManagersernive.png
```

Thank you.

Comment: Cute Teddy, FYI please add responses in the "comments" section under an answer, rather than adding discussions as an Answer.